# Connection to remote mysql server not working even with bind-address, privileges and ip tables configured

Tags: mysql, tcp

So I've been trying to connect remotely to my MySQL server but I can't get it to work. Here's what I did.

I set up `bind-address=0.0.0.0` to be able to connect from anywhere (I first tried with my own IP address but it didn't work so I set it up like that for now). I also don't have `skip-networking` activated.

I added privileges to the database I want to access for the user I'm using. Also flushed privileges right after.

I set up iptables to allow a connection through port 3306 from anywhere just like that :

`21   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:3306`

I checked with `netstat` to make sure mysql was listening correctly, this is what I got :

`tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:3306      0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      18878/mysqld`

I also tried to `telnet <ip> 3306` and I simply get the message :

`Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed`

I've been searching and trying to figure this out but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Everything works locally but I can't get it to work remotely.

Comment: Have you also checked if the outgoing connection is allowed on your client/router? You can use this link for testing: [Outgoing port tester](http://portquiz.net:3306/)

Comment: Yep, it's allowed, and I can see the webpage at your link. It says "You have reached this page on port 3306".

Comment: please check the incoming ports on your server too; here's a tool for this: [open port check tool](http://www.canyouseeme.org/)

Comment: Hmm, it does seem to be closed, but I don't understand why. If mysql is correctly listening on port 3306 from any ip and iptables is set up correctly, what's causing the problem?

Comment: Is the remote server in the same network? Or is a firewall in-between the client and the server?

Comment: Right now I'm trying to connect from my home computer which is not in the same network. I'm not sure what firewall other than iptables could be blocking the connection...unless my hosting provider blocks it? They don't say anything about blocking ports on their website and they even have a tutorial on how to setup remote mysql connection (the same way I did) so I don't think they do.

Comment: could you please try following command in the terminal: `iptables -nL | grep 8999`?  Whats the output?

Comment: Nothing...but why look for 8999 ?

Comment: Sry I've got the command from the web and forgot to correct the port. Please try with `iptables -nL | grep 3306`

Comment: Gives me the same output I posted above : `ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:3306`

Comment: Now I'm pretty much sure that the firewall of your provider is blocking the connection. I think it's best to write an email asking them to check the availability of the port.

Comment: So I ended up stopping the iptables service to see if it would work, and it did, so at least I know the problem is iptables, but now I'm not sure what's wrong in my iptables config ... trying to figure it out.

Comment: strange, regarding the output your iptables should work. Here's a source with some explanation on how to enable mysql: [Iptables allow mysql](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-18-allow-mysql-server-incoming-request.html)